# Multiplying samples array by scaling factor gives ambiguous results when reading/writing .wav files

Tags: python, scipy, wav

I need to manipulate some `.wav` files, and I am using the `scipy.io.wavfile` module to help me with this task.

I ran into a problem when I tried to understand how the `read` and `write` functions work.

I have a sample file `input_file.wav`. The code I wrote that worked as expected was:

```
def scale(filename):
    fs, x = wavfile.read(filename)
    wavfile.write('test_output.wav', fs, x)
    return
scale('input_file.wav')
```

The input and output files looked identical when I imported them into Audacity, and sounded identical on my headphones.
I ran into issues when I executed the following code.

```
def scale(filename):
    fs, x = wavfile.read(filename)
    x1 = x * 0.5
    wavfile.write('test_output1.wav', fs, x1)
    return
scale('input_file.wav')
```

I expected that the output would be half as loud (since I multiplied the value of each sample by 0.5. But when I imported it into Audacity, the file was loud to the point of severe distortion.

The same thing happened when I multipled by `1.01`, `1.0001`, `0.1`, and a number of other values I tried - massively boosted volume to the point of large distortions.

The file started to sound identical (and look identical when imported into Audacity) when I multiplied the sample array by a value of `1/32767` or so (which is `1/(2^15-1)`). This is strange because the values in the sample array returned by the `read()` function are definitely not identical.

**Why do the output files from the write operation sound the same when the scaling value is either 1 or 1/32767, two very different numbers?**

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: If it helps, the output of `x.dtype` (the `dtype` attribute of the sample array returned by `read()` is `int16`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` has `dtype` `np.int16`, then `x1` has `dtype` `np.float64`.  It appears that `scipy.io.wavfile.write` attempts to write 64 bit floating values to the file, even though the documentation only mentions 32 bit floating point formats.  You can work around the problem by converting `x1` to `int16`, or by normalizing the values in `x1` to the range [-1, 1] (or [-0.5, 0.5], or to whatever range you want in [-1, 1]).  That is, you can use

```
wavfile.write('test_output1.wav', fs, np.round(x1).astype(x.dtype))  # If x has an integer dtype
```

or

```
wavfile.write('test_output1.wav', fs, (x1/2**15).astype(np.float32))
```